# How to change the hard drive and directory of installation of Gnome Boxes Virtual Machines?

Tags: gnome-boxes

I want to use gnome boxes, but since I have a SSD + HDD on my laptop, I want to change the boxes image to my HDD instead of SSD, how can I change the location of the images? I checked that Gnome Boxes did not have this feature, can I do this through the terminal?

Answer (score 2):

Image files in "B" are stored in `~/.local/share/gnome-boxes/images`. It will be sufficient to move the `~/.local/share/gnome-boxes` to a directory on your other disk, then place a symbolic link in the original place that points to the new location.

Of course, do this while Boxes is not running.

Moving a directory then creating a symbolic link are standard operations, so yes, this can easily be done using the terminal with a `mv` and an `ln -s` command.